# Can I make a django model object immutable?

Tags: django, django-models

There are places in my code where I want to temporarily change some of the attributes on a model object without changing the data in the database. Obviously Django and Python make this very easy to do, I just need to set the attribute without calling save.

But I'd like to know if there's a common pattern for making the object immutable so I don't accidentally call save somewhere later down the line and screw up the data in my database. And maybe "immutable" isn't the right word here, it's more like disassociating the object with the model so data can't ever get back to the database.

My first idea was to just override the save method to do nothing, would this be enough?

Answer (score 16):

I know this question is pretty old, but is very much still relevant.

The best, if somewhat curt solution I've come up with to date looks like so:

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    # fields, etc...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:
            raise ValidationError("you may not edit an existing %s" % self._meta.model_name)
        super(ModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This way users are informed that the action they are performing is unsupported, rather than just silently failing.

Comment: This seems the most reasonable to me. Is there any way that `save()` can be bypassed and this not work?

Comment: I don't think so. From the docs: "To save an object back to the database, call save()" and "If you want customized saving behavior, you can override this save() method. See Overriding predefined model methods for more details." and finally "A classic use-case for overriding the built-in methods is if you want something to happen whenever you save an object. For example (see save() for documentation of the parameters it accepts)"

Comment: FYI this shouldn't be considered 100% save, as you can still change the object with `queryset.update()` (it bypasses `save()` method).

Comment: Django now has `bulk_update` which will also bypass this method.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest thing to do here, if you are trying to make your *instance* immutable, is to write a little wrapper:

```
def _model_save_base(*args, **kwargs):
    raise NotImplementedError("Cannot save a frozen instance.")

def freeze_instance(obj):
    obj.save_base = _model_save_base
```

Then you can call freeze_instance on your object:

```
blog = Blog.objects.get(name='Django')
blog.save()  # writes to the database
freeze_instance(blog)
blog.save()  # NotImplementedError
```

You can always improve this by making a custom exception. Or you can add freeze_instance to your Blog model. But that's mostly stylistic.

Answer (score 4):

Overriding the `save()` method of a normal model in such a manner can be troublesome, so you should consider using a [proxy model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) with a `save()` method that throws an exception if called.

Comment: How can it be troublesome when I'm just overriding it on an instance? I would imagine that it just changes the 'save' attribute on that instance, not the model itself, right?

Comment: Well, changing a method on an instance instead of a class is troublesome regardless.

Comment: i like the idea of throwing an exception when called so you know where your code might freak out!

Answer (score 1):

There are also a few libraries out there, like [django-immutablemodel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-immutablemodel/0.3.3) and [django-immutablefield](https://bitbucket.org/robmadole/django-immutablefield) that provide a more comprehensive api for immutable models.

Comment: FYI, both of these modules are broken with Py3 / modern Django versions.